# Three.js Hello World and include file

Tags: html, three.js

I am starting to learn html5 and WebGl. I start with this [example](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/).

I have inlcuded  `build.three.js` with `<script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>`

and then adding what is in the [example](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/) in a another script but I cannot make it works.

Does anyone as any idea on how to include the `JQuery` script? I cannot find it in the source of three.js

What am I missing? Does anyone can provide me the html source of an three.js hello world?

Answer (score 2):

add this to your page:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

same example on here http://jsfiddle.net/jZxfZ/